# Feedback page not responding in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, feedback

I am trying to submit a feedback after logging in the user. The Data in not being inserted in the database nor is it displaying any message if the form is left empty.

This is my controller:

```
function dashboard(){
        $this->load->model('stud_model');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Id', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('feedback', 'Feedback', 'required');
        $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $data = array(
                    'Name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                    'Email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'Feedback' => $this->input->post('feedback'),
                );
            $submit = $this->stud_model->insert_feedback($data);
            if($submit) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Feedback Successfully Submitted !');
                redirect('Students/enter');
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Feedback could not be Submitted !');
                redirect('Students/enter');
            }
        }else{$this->load->View('dashboard', $data);}
    }

function enter(){
        if ($this->session->userdata('username') != '') {
            $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
            $this->load->View('dashboard', $data);
        }else{
            redirect('Students/log');
        }
    }
    function logout(){
        $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
        redirect('Students/index');
    }
```

This is my view:

```
<body>
    <h1 align="center">My Dashboard</h1><br><br>
    <h3 align="left">Welcome <?php echo $username ?> !</h3>
    <form action="http://localhost/ci/index.php/Students/dashboard" align="center">
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>  
    <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $username ?>"><br>
        Email Id : <br><input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
        Feedback:<br><br>
        <textarea name="feedback" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata("message"); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/Students/logout'; ?>">Logout</a>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is my Model:

```
function insert_feedback($data){
        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->insert("feedback", $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

Comment: What is the error? try with error reporting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Error myself.
I had forgot to add 'method="post"' to my form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use

```
    $this->load->library('database');
```

Instead

```
    $this->load->database();
```

Comment: Got the error myself. I Had forgot to add method="post" to the form. Anyways Thanx

Answer (score 0):

> Change setting on config folder in autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation', 'session');

$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');
```

Comment: Got the error myself. I Had forgot to add method="post" to the form. Anyways Thanx

Comment: In Form tag method deceleration is not required.